# 1980 horror graphic novel anthology featuring a kitsune and a samurai raid

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for this graphic novel, and on the cover, the image looked like "Swamp Thing", but it wasn't.

There are horror anthologies within this novel. There was a story about a kitsune (Japanese fox demon); this woman transforms into a fox,and wanders around a lot, but a hoard of Samurai attack her tiny village. The leader of the samurai decapitates her life long friend and protector,asks if the dead man was a friend or a lover,and then takes her hostage.

I can't remember the rest of this story, and I vaguely remember the orders,but there was a great deal of decapitation in most of them, with the exception of a story about a man driving down the road during a rain storm, sees a wolf laying unconscious on the side of the road, so he pulls over and takes the beast home,and nurses it back to health. A friendship is formed, and when this man goes to confront this business rival in his office, he has the wolf by his side as an intimidation tactic, but it backfires, when the businessman summons his own wolf for the impending confrontation.

There are a few more things that I remember about this graphic horror novel. Another story tells of a man going to his woodshed and getting an ax, which he carries into his home and decapitates a woman, that was standing there talking to him.

This book came out in the year 1980 around Spring time. Any help offered in finding out the name of this graphic novel will be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to SFF! This is a good amount of detail, but try to look at [this list](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and see if you could add anything else. In particular, what language did you read it in, and in what country? Do you happen to remember the publisher? How thick was it?

Comment: Are you really sure about that timeframe?  1980 is _very_ early for a graphic novel.  The first "original" graphic novel (Contract With God) was from 1978, and there were maybe only a half dozen books done in 1980 or earlier.  Even TPB collections of issues were incredibly rare, not becoming commonplace until the mid-90's.  If you're sure about the year, are you certain it was a graphic novel?

Comment: It was a horror comic book,and I believe it was an American publishing company, for it was in English. I wish I could remember more, because I'd like to find it.I found it in my cousin's comic collection here in Cleveland,Ohio.I do remember for a certainty,that it was the year 1980.

Comment: @MarkThompson That may depend on your definition of "graphic novel". According to [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/graphic_novel), a graphic novel is simply a comic book with one story; of which there had been many before 1978.

Comment: @MrLister not necessarily - see [my answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/771/how-are-graphic-novels-different-from-comic-books) over at Literature SE.

Comment: @Gallifreyan But the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphic_novel) you refer to in there also says the exact definition is debated, the earliest example they could find was from 1828 and the term itself was coined in 1964. I stand by my statement.

Comment: It wasn't very thick(like the size of People magazine),and the pages were in black and white with a color cover

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for your help, but after some extensive research, I found the book!It's titled [Creepy #100 special edition](https://www.comics.org/issue/32538/) August 1978 with a picture of Cthullu kneeling on the cover, as if he's holding the book title on his shoulders.The story about the kitsune was called "Tale of a Fox",and the one about the wolf found laying outside,as if injured, "Hell Hound". Amazon.com sold it to me,so all is good in the neighborhood!

[image: Magazine cover]

That issue is [also available via The Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/warrencreepy-100).

Image from "Tale of a Fox" showing the decapitation:
[image: Decapitation of hireling]

Image from "Hell Hound" showing end with other wolf:
[image: He's got a wolf too]

And, just for good measure, the axe scene from "Wisper of Dark Eyes":
[image: Decapitation by axe from wood shed]